# On Google Sheets, how to reduce a table with multiple values per date to one row for each date and a total of the values for that date?

Tags: google-sheets

I have something like this:

```
date        value
2022/01/02  4
2022/01/02  3
2022/01/01  2
2022/01/01  1
```

and I want another table computed from that which has a single row for each date and the sum of the values for that date:

```
Date        Value
2022/01/02  7
2022/01/01  3
```

etc...how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### solution #1

Use a pivot table to do what you expect !

### solution #2

```
=SORT(QUERY(A2:B,"select A,sum(B) group by A label sum(B) ''"))
```

with duration, use

```
=SORT(QUERY({A2:A,arrayformula(value(B2:B))},"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"))
```

Comment: Thanks...that seems to work for the fake example I gave. Unfortunately, in my real data, the 'value' is a 'duration' (ie the difference between two other cells on the same row, each of which contains a time).
That seems to cause a problem. If I make a duplicate column but format the values as 'number', and use that instead of the one formatted with 'duration', then that works fine.
It is, somehow, an unsatisfactory solution...any ideas?

Comment: Try the new answer.